# Play 2 videos in a row using Timer

Tags: swift, video, timer, avplayer, swift3

I'm looking to play a video after another video using a timer (the 1st video is 414 seconds long).

**The problems I'm running into:**

-Instead of Video 2, it's just showing the last frame of Video 1. I can hear the audio of Video 2, but can only see the last frame of Video 1. Plus- the framing works for Video 1, but gets all messed up when video 2 starts. I understand there is a simpler way to have the video fit the screen size- any help there would be appreciated as well.

**Here is what I'm currently working with:**

```
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

var player = AVPlayer()
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
var player2 = AVPlayer()
let playerViewController2 = AVPlayerViewController()
var countTimer = Timer()
var count = Double()
var moviePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Video1", ofType: "m4v")

override func viewDidLoad() {
 playVideo()
 countTimer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(countFunc), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
 RunLoop.current.add(countTimer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)

func countFunc()
{
    count += 0.01
    if(count > 414.0 && count < 414.1)
    {
        playVideo2()
    }


func playVideo()
{

    moviePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Video1", ofType: "m4v")

        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: moviePath!)
        player = AVPlayer(url: url)

        playerViewController.player = player

        playerViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width * ((-146)/(374)), y: (self.view.frame.height * (146)/(667 * 1.014)), width: self.view.frame.height, height: self.view.frame.width * 1.01)
        playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = false
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.001, animations: {
            self.playerViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat(M_PI)/2)

        })
        self.view.addSubview(playerViewController.view)
        self.player.play()

}

func playVideo2()
{
    print("Video2")
    playerViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
    player.pause()

    moviePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Video2", ofType: "m4v")

    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: moviePath!)
    player2 = AVPlayer(url: url)

    playerViewController2.player = player

    playerViewController2.view.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width * ((-219)/(561)), y: (self.view.frame.height * (219)/(1000.5 * 1.521)), width: self.view.frame.height, height: self.view.frame.width * 1.515)
    playerViewController2.showsPlaybackControls = false
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.001, animations: {
        self.playerViewController2.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat(M_PI)/2)

    })
    self.view.addSubview(playerViewController2.view)
    self.player2.play()
}
```